# Custom PUT route with FormRequest in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, routes, request, entity

I want to make a custom PUT route to manage AJAX request

```
Route::post('some/{id}/another/new', 'SomeController@store');
Route::put('some/{cid}/another/{id}/edit', 'SomeController@update');
```

and I want to use `FormRequest` as a request parameter

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(DirectionRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    $direction = Direction::create($data);        
    return response()->json($direction, 201);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Direction  $direction
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(DirectionRequest $request, $clientId, $directionId )
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    $direction = Direction::find($directionId);
    $direction->update($data);
    return response()->json($direction, 201);
}
```

DirectionRequest.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DirectionRequest extends FormRequest
{

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'country' => 'required|string|max:255'
    ];
}

/**
 * 
 * @return type
 */
public function all($keys = null) {
    $data = parent::all();
    $data['created_by'] = Auth::User()->id;
    return $data;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param Validator $validator
 * @throws HttpResponseException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
}
```

and AJAX call

```
const editData = new FormData();
editData.append("country", document.getElementById('country').value);

return fetch(`/some/` + sidId + `/another/` + id + `/edit`, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: editData,
    headers: new Headers({
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    })
 })
.then(response => {
   if (!response.ok) {
           throw new Error(response.statusText)
   }
   return response.json()
 })
 .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
 });
```

And I get `422 Unprocessible Entity` error which return all my model fields with errrors, but they are filled and sended by the AJAX request.

How to use FormRequest in custom route to use validation rules from it? I dont want to copy code with rules because I use that FormRequest in another method (store) and there it works

Simple `Request` shows put data, but `FormRequest` doesn't

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(editData);`? Also, can you check the network tab in your browser to confirm that the request data is in the correct format?

Comment: I've update code block. Simple Request shows put data, but FormRequest don't.
I use the same code for `POST` method and there it seems to be all right

Comment: In that case can you add the code you had when you were using just the `Request` and the code you have in your `DirectionRequest` class?

Comment: Can you set the method to post but then do somethign like this in your form: {{ method_field('PUT') }}

Comment: @RossWilson I've update code again. Is this is what you want to see?
@BradGoldsmith Did U mean set AJAX to POST instead PUT and then do everything like `store` method inc controller?

Comment: Looking at it you're only submitting the `country` field but you said that  `country`, `country_code`, `city`, `postcode`, `address_1`, `created_by` and `client_id` are all required.

Comment: @RossWilson that's not my point, I've just cut the code.  When I press submit button I'm getting validation exception with every fields and Request doesnt get into controller and in FormRequest post is empty.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ajax-formdata-and-put-fails

Comment: @RossWilson thanks for the link. There'se some helpful informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After follow @RossWilson link 
[laracast.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ajax-formdata-and-put-fails) I've change my request type to `POST` and then I could validate inputs with `FormRequest` rules and other stuff from it